# Kusto number of overlapping intervals in a time range

Tags: azure, kql

I'm trying to write a Kusto query that needs to count how many intervals overlap for a certain date range. This is how my table looks like:

```
userID |  interval1         | interval2
24     |  21.1.2012 10:40   | 21.1.2012 11:00
25     |  21.1.2012 9:55    | 21.1.2012 10:50
```

I would like to to consider the time range given by [min(interval1), max(interval2)] with 1s step and for each instance of this interval I would like to know how many intervals from the previous table overlap. For example, for 21.1.2012 10:00 there is only one interval but for 10:45 there are two intervals overlapping.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I would like to know how many users were concurrently accessing my API per second

Comment: in fact not just concurrent access to some API but concurrent access per certain interval to some shared resource resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every interval1 indicates additional user's session start (+1).
Every interval2 indicates additional user's session end (-1).
The accumulated sum indicates the number of active sessions.

**Solution 1 (Rendering level)**
`with (accumulate=True)`

```
let t = (datatable (userID:int,interval1:datetime,interval2:datetime)
[
     24 ,datetime(2012-01-21 10:40) ,datetime(2012-01-21 11:00)
    ,25 ,datetime(2012-01-21 09:55) ,datetime(2012-01-21 10:50)
]);
let from_dttm = datetime(2012-01-21 09:30);
let to_dttm   = datetime(2012-01-21 11:30);
let sessions_starts = (t | project delta =  1, dttm = interval1);
let sessions_ends =   (t | project delta = -1, dttm = interval2);
union sessions_starts, sessions_ends
| make-series delta = sum(delta) on dttm from from_dttm to to_dttm step 1s
| render timechart with (accumulate=True)
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WRTW/DIAyG75HyH3wMUiIBaw5j6m2X3XebpoolnpoNkgrMdumPn0nX7KMNCAnZL4/tF4cEBFuoeku8XxxClSKGh3szjFTzwfBhnTKcRxo8LiG9hERZPJUF5KU3UJ/DlZZKN1I1WoGSZiPFSk4ZKcUJUOv2ukjemrZdA0jTZsCzuCsLxwO9hsnveiLPg63AbuRZTNNJCitibu9HHDHGYRrjLpINFLNxBEc4hOkNO4IeHVkOgqrhu/7i4AUCxz4D4DqiuUTojEgjP/7fR/2XWhZH8PYdG/7IAePCjMlX810AM2Z6tuqXXzQtfkTCA6iZFRiKAbIz3Z7rwedAe6hs1yWfHHu2fQwJxRdCU64cTAIAAA==)

**Solution 2 (Data level)**
`mv-apply + row_cumsum`

```
let t = (datatable (userID:int,interval1:datetime,interval2:datetime)
[
     24 ,datetime(2012-01-21 10:40) ,datetime(2012-01-21 11:00)
    ,25 ,datetime(2012-01-21 09:55) ,datetime(2012-01-21 10:50)
]);
let from_dttm = datetime(2012-01-21 09:30);
let to_dttm   = datetime(2012-01-21 11:30);
let sessions_starts = (t | project delta =  1, dttm = interval1);
let sessions_ends =   (t | project delta = -1, dttm = interval2);
union sessions_starts, sessions_ends
| make-series delta = sum(delta) on dttm from from_dttm to to_dttm step 1s
| mv-apply  delta to typeof(long), dttm to typeof(datetime) on (project active_users = row_cumsum(delta), dttm)
| render timechart with (xcolumn=dttm, ycolumns=active_users)
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WSQW6DMBBF95xillgCyaZhUSp23fQMVYVcmDS0BiN7SBoph++YEJKmBYQE4/+f5w82SEBQQtxo4vvdIMSjR/fyXLQ9Jfyg22ujCl5HajtcStlSEtFrBOHKNpBcinEmVZZKlWYKlCw2UqysqUJKMfmTLP9fIx+LPF/zyyJn/5t4igxn2TrbVQ1Rx5lWUA9y1pI9K2FFy60tWo/et7b3lSftyIeJEZxgcPYTa4IGDWkugkpg3n0Z3T0B+2bVn/71Z+wfe3be95D8RkYn6PQXpvzzWvQL0Y9dPL0LYMTEDjO6GRTZZRKecAA1ofapHgZzhBkURMcB7TY2tv8Qc5fX6nIWwi7xJZauqd1jFQ5UiOzsoarH7trSGSN4P8cR0EFA1DtOB4eWdhB/19aMXV8GWQLH85cvb7niB0RsX/XDAgAA)

Comment: Just realized that there is a much simpler way if what you need is a solution on the rendering level. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample from the Kusto docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuredataexplorer#chart-concurrent-sessions-over-time

```
X
| mv-expand samples = range(bin(interval1, 1m), interval2, 1m)
| summarize count_userID = count() by bin(todatetime(samples), 1m)
```